# How to change the font size dynamically in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, font-size

I understand one can use `preferredFontForTextStyle` for dynamic font size. How do I use the same to change font size of UIWebView ? How to get "FONT SIZE" preference value, to change font size of HTML page loaded in UIWebView